# webRTC recording tab screen with tab audio not wroking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, media, web-audio-api

I used webRTC, node js, and react to build a fully functional video conferencing app that can support up to 4 users and uses mesh architecture. After that, I wanted to add a record meeting feature, so I added it. However, it only records my own audio from my microphone and remote stream audio is not recorded in the media recorder. Why is that?

here is a simple code snippet that shows how I get my tab screen stream

```
const toBeRecordedStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    video: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,

      frameRate: {
        max:30,
        ideal: 24,
      },
    },
    audio: true,
  });
```

After receiving the tab stream, I used audio context to combine the tab audio with my microphone audio and record it.

```
 const vp9Codec = "video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus";
 const vp9Options = {
    mimeType: vp9Codec,
 };
 const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
 const outputStream = new MediaStream();
 const micStream = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(localStream);
 const screenAudio = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(screenStream);
 const destination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
 screenAudio.connect(destination);
 micStream.connect(destination);
 outputStream.addTrack(screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
 outputStream.addTrack(destination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
 if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(vp9Codec)) {
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(outputStream, vp9Options);
} else {
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(outputStream);
}
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handelDataAvailable;
mediaRecorder.start();
```

Four video and audio streams are visible on the screen, but only my voice and the video of the tab are recorded

and I am working with the Chrome browser because I am aware that Firefox does not support tab audio, but Chrome and Edge do.

Comment: Ever fixed this? I'm having the same issue..

Comment: @Dude The issue has not been resolved yet.